# Get a flat map of all types from kaitai struct

Tags: python, kaitai-struct

I generated a simple parser in python with kaitai struct. Now I would like to achieve something similar that the kaitai web ide does in the hex view (https://ide.kaitai.io/devel/) to map the types to a binary byte by byte. How can I use the parser to achieve this? A small snippet would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoking the kaitai compiler with the *--read-pos* option will create a dictionary with byte offsets. The directory is named *_debug*.